# format survey responses in to tidy R data frame

Tags: r, csv

We use a third-party survey app that only gives HTML responses, which I then scrape into CSV files that look like this:

```
2,"Rank features by frequency of use ","AMER","JAPAC","EMEA","Total"
2.1,"Stored procedures ",,,,
"Never",,1,2,1,4
"Sometimes (<50% of applications)",,10,6,5,21
"Often (>50%)",,7,4,2,13
"Always",,1,0,0,1
2.2,"Triggers ",,,,
"Never","  ",4,3,2,9
"Sometimes (<50% of applications)","  ",13,9,3,25
"Often (>50%)","  ",2,0,2,4
"Always","  ",0,0,1,1
```

This goes on, and sometimes has more than three responses. I'd like it to be in the "tidy" format of:

```
Q.Num, Response, Never, Sometimes, Often, Always, Other.Response, 
2.1, "Stored Procedures", 4, 21, 13, 1
2.2, "Triggers", 9, 25, 4, 1
```

(I can manage mapping the questions to the numbers elsewhere and ditching the regional data for now)

I suppose I could do this with a loop (more easily in python), but I'm hoping there's a more "R-like" manner...

Comment: Look at `read.csv()` with the `skip` argument then subset the resulting data.frame

Comment: Please post a snippet of actual html responses. R can certainly parse that into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a tidy `data.frame` I thought I would make one for you with the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d <- read.csv("path/to/data.csv")

col_n = head(d$X2, 5)[-1] #Obtaining "Always, Never, Often, Sometimes"

d_1 <- d[!d$X2 %in% col_n, c("X2", "Rank.features.by.frequency.of.use.")]

d_2 <- d[d$X2 %in% col_n, !names(d) %in% "Rank.features.by.frequency.of.use."]

d_2$Q.Num <- rep(d_1$X2, each = length(col_n))

d_2$Response <- rep(d_1$Rank.features.by.frequency.of.use., each = length(col_n))

d_2 %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Q.Num, -Response, -X2) %>%
  spread(X2, value) %>%
  rename(Country = key)
```

This data set includes all the countries, rather than only the totals as outlined in your example.  However, from your post it appears as if you will need country level data.